# 'router-outlet' is not a known element Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy empezando con angular y estoy utilizando [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) para utilizar sus componentes, cuando quiero importar un modulo y declararlo en `declarations`

```
//ANGULAR-MATERIAL
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MatToolbarModule //este es el modulo que quiero declarar
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

me da el siguiente error

```
src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' 
of this component to suppress this message.

1 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

me parece muy raro por que genere la app con el modulo de route para poder utilizar rutas y eso ya lo configure y anda perfecto, pero el problema aparece cuando quiero utilizar un modulo

Comment: El error se debe al routing, que contiene tu AppRoutingModule?

Answer (score 1):

El arreglo `declarations` es solo para componentes. Debes de quitar el modulo `MatToolbarModule`.

```
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MatToolbarModule //Eliminalo de aqui
  ],
```

y registrarlo en los `imports`

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule 
  ],
```

Las declaraciones son para los componentes, mientras que los imports sirven para traer un modulo que contenga servicios y componentes.

Comment: el componente sigue sin renderizarse, ahora el error es `'mat-toolbar' is not a known element`